# Google Adwords Keyword Tool API to automatically extract data onto a website

Tags: api, keyword, google-ads-api

Im looking to use Google Adwords Keyword tool data on a website. Ive been looking around in the API and I cant find much to match what I need. I noticed a lot of keyword research tool websites use google as their main source for their information. How would I go about doing this and extracting the data and have it run on a website automatically so it wouldnt need to be updated manually each month?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Traffic Estimator service in the AdWords API:

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201409/TrafficEstimatorService

Be warned that this is notoriously inaccurate (which is odd given that you would think Google had its own data to call upon!)

Answer (score 0):

I use the TargetingIdea service in the AdWords API to generate lists of keywords to use for building AdWords campaigns. (https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201409/TargetingIdeaService.TargetingIdea)

First off you need an API key - they're not that easy to get and your app needs to offer a whole lot of features to meet the required minimum functionality - take a look here  https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/requirements

Once you've jumped over that hurdle you get the data from Google by sending a request to the service. That request includes some targeting criteria like location and language and also a "seed" keyword. You can also specify if you want closely related results or broadly related results.

For example if you sold tractors you'd put 'tractors' in as a seed keyword and then the API would return either closely related terms like 'tractors for sale', 'used tractor spares' etc or more broadly related terms like 'agricultural machinery'.